# Python error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

```
distances = {   "u":0,
                "v":0,
                "w":0,
                "x":0,
                "y":0,
                "z":0 }

Np = ["u"]
nodes = ["u","v","w","x","y","z"]
max = 20;
for node in nodes:
        if (node+"-u") in dictionary:
                distances[node] = dictionary["u-"+node]
        else:
                distances[node] = max;


while Np != nodes:
        for node in nodes:
                if node not in Np:
                        if (distances[node] < max):
                                min = distances[node]
                                minnode = node;
                                max = min;
        Np.append(minnode);
        print(Np);
        for node in nodes:
                if node not in Np:
                        if (node+"-"+minnode) in dictionary:
                                distances[node] = min(distances[node], distances[minnode] + dictionary[node+"-"+minnode]);
```

please help where i am going wrong, i am getting error at last line of code:

```
distances[node] = min(distances[node], distances[minnode] + dictionary[node+"-"+minnode]);
```

it is saying that i am doing typeError of 'int' but i traced code back to start, i can't see what is wrong. I am using dictionary object and list object, maybe that is the cause? please look at code and mend

Comment: `min = distances[node]` You redefined `min` so it's a number, not the function that calculates minimum.

Comment: Don't use variables that have the same name as standard functions and types.

Comment: `max`, `min` are both builtin functions. we'd avoid to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
min = distances[node]
minnode = node;
max = min;
```

From there we know that the `min` is a variable of a number or something, but you use it as a function in your last line of code.

```
distances[node] = min(distances[node], distances[minnode] + dictionary[node+"-"+minnode]);
```

Try using another name for your variable.